6N137 opto-coupler with AC input takes a lot of time to trigger
I am designing a zero-crossing circuit to connect it to a RasPi Pico W input. I am using a 6N137 from Liteon. I have a problem because it takes around 200 microseconds to turn on with an input of 40V RMS, a frequency of 50 Hz ,resistor of 3 kΩ and a pull-up resistor of 550 Ω. This is due to the time the AC input takes to reach the specified threshold values for the opto-coupler. Note that when testing the optocoupler with a Step input it works perfectly. How can I speed up the input without damaging the device?
Here is an image of the measurement: Green is AC input, yellow is opto output.

Here is the test circuit. Please note that the simulation result differs from reality. C1 is a bypass capacitor recommended in the datasheet:


What's the AC peak-peak voltage? A schematic would be nice. Where exactly are the probes attached?

What time would you consider acceptable?

The test circuits in the datasheet seem to indicate that the timing specs are valid for 7.5mA drive current.  With your 3k input resistor and the emitter's aprox 1.5V forward voltage, that would require you to be using a 24V supply to drive it. So ... what supply voltage to you actually have on the emitter side?

input is 40VRMS AC. an acceptable delay would be <5us

FYI, comments are for discussion; information should be edited into the question.

@mhdAwskamel Just doing a quick sanity check, I took a look at a circuit I designed some time ago using the 6N137. Notebook says that with an input pulse of 1 mA and a rise time of 500 ns at the input the output's rise time was about an average of 1.3 us (over a few devices.) The output resistor was 22 k and Vcc was 5 V. This tells me that your goal may be achievable. But that you should figure on at least 1 us delay. This cuts into your 5 us margin.

@mhdAwskamel  What's the AC frequency? (I may have missed seeing it.) It matters very much here. The fastest rate of change will be $\left[2\pi,\cdot, f\cdot, 40:\text{V}\cdot \sqrt{2}\right]:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}$. If you multiply that by the very short period left in your margin (at most $4:\mu\text{s}$, given my notebook) then that tells you how few millivolts of change near the crossing that you have to work with, at best.

You say your input is 40V-RMS. Does that mean you're driving the opto directly from the input sine wave (no comparator or anything like that)? If that's the case then you can't expect the opto to even begin turning on until the input voltage has risen above about 1.5v, and even then it's going to turn on sloooowly as the input sine wave voltage rises. With a 50Hz sine wave, it'll take over 80uSec from zero-cross until the input to the opto gets high enough to even begin to turn the emitter on.

Your test circuit drives the opto with a sine wave. The datasheet test circuit drives it with a square wave. That makes a huge difference to the behavior of the opto. The long delay you get by driving it directly from the sine wave will probably be fairly consistent, so it's something you could calibrate for in your system - for example you can start a timer when you get your delayed zero-cross with the timer period set to time out at the instant of the following real zero-cross.
